# How to prepare large datasets with Patsy's API?

Tags: python, data-processing, patsy

I'm running a logistic regression and having trouble using Patsy's API to prepare the data when it is bigger than a small sample.

Using the `dmatrices` function directly on a DataFrame, I am left with this abrupt error ( please note, I spun up an EC2 with 300GB of RAM after encountering this on my laptop, and got the same error ):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "My_File.py", line 22, in <module>
   df, return_type="dataframe")
File "/root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 297, in dmatrices
 NA_action, return_type)
File "/root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 156, in do_highlevel_design
return_type=return_type)
File "/root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/build.py", line 989, in build_design_matrices
results.append(builder._build(evaluator_to_values, dtype))
File "/root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/build.py", line 821, in _build
m = DesignMatrix(np.empty((num_rows, self.total_columns), dtype=dtype),
MemoryError
```

So, I combed through [Patsy's docs](https://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API-reference.html) and found this gem:

```
patsy.incr_dbuilder(formula_like, data_iter_maker, eval_env=0)
    Construct a design matrix builder incrementally from a large data set.
```

However, the method is sparsely documented, and the source code is largely uncommented.

I have arrived at this code:

```
def iter_maker():
    with open("test.tsv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter="\t")
        for row in reader:
            yield(row)


y, dta = incr_dbuilders("s ~ C(x) + C(y):C(rgh) + \
C(z):C(f) + C(r):C(p) + C(q):C(w) + \
C(zr):C(rt) + C(ff):C(djjj) + C(hh):C(tt) + \
C(bb):lat + C(jj):lng + C(ee):C(bb) + C(qq):C(uu)",
        iter_maker)

df = dmatrix(dta, {}, 0, "drop", return_type="dataframe")
```

but I receive `PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'ff' is not defined`

This is being thrown because _try_incr_builders (called from dmatrix) is returning None [on line 151 of highlevel.py](https://github.com/pydata/patsy/blob/master/patsy/highlevel.py)

What is the correct way to use these Patsy functions to prepare my data? Any examples or guidance you may have will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` and `dta` are `DesignInfo` objects -- they encode all the information needed to take a row of a data frame and convert it to a row of a design matrix. They do *not*, though, have your actual data in them -- to get a piece of your design matrix, you have to give them a piece of your data. To use them, you need to do something like

```
for data_chunk in iter_maker():
  y_chunk, design_chunk = dmatrices((y, dta), data_chunk,
                                    NA_action="drop", return_type="dataframe")
  # do something with y_chunk and design_chunk
  # ...
```